# Function is not receiving what I send as a const char *

Tags: c, strcat

```
static char DEFAULT_DELIMITER = ',';
char *calculator_retrieveFirstToken(char *numbers, const char * delimiters) {
    //if (delimiters[strlen(delimiters)-1] == DEFAULT_DELIMITER)
    if (delimiters[1] == DEFAULT_DELIMITER) {
        return strtok(numbers, delimiters);
    }
    else {
        char linefeed = '\n';
        strtok(numbers, &linefeed);
        return strtok(NULL, delimiters);
    }
}

char calculator_findDelimiter(const char *numbers) {
    char delimiter = DEFAULT_DELIMITER;
    if (strlen(numbers) >= 4
        && numbers[0] == '/'
        && numbers[1] == '/') {
        delimiter = numbers[2];
    }
    return delimiter;
}

double calculator_add(char *numbers) {
    char delimiters[] = "\n";
    char *token = NULL;

    char mainDelimiter = calculator_findDelimiter(numbers);
    strcat(delimiters, &mainDelimiter);
    token = calculator_retrieveFirstToken(numbers, delimiters);
    return calculator_addEveryToken(token, delimiters);
}
```

Weirdest is happening when I debug into the calculator_retrieveFirstToken function.

Example of numbers input : ""

mainDelimiter is equal to ','

after the strcat call : delimiters is equal to : "\n,"

When I go into the calculator_retrieveFirstToken function the delimiters param is equal to : 
"\n,\n,"

I don't understand how is that suppose to work....Something is wrong with my strcat call?

Here's the main

```
#include "calculator_kata.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

static char numbers[50];

static bool equals(const double expected, const double received)
{
    double epsilon = 1e-7;
    return fabs(received - expected) < epsilon;
}

static void test_addEmptyString_shouldReturnZero()
{
    strcpy(numbers, "");
    const double sum = calculator_add(numbers);
    assert(equals(0, sum));
}

static void test_addOneNumber_shouldReturnThisNumber()
{
    strcpy(numbers, "42");
    const double sum = calculator_add(numbers);
    assert(equals(42, sum));
}

static void test_addTwoNumbers_shouldReturnTheSum()
{
    const double TWENTY_ONE = 9+10;
    strcpy(numbers, "9,10");

    const double sum = calculator_add(numbers);

    assert(equals(TWENTY_ONE, sum));
}

static void test_addAnyQtyOfNumbers_shouldReturnTheSum()
{
    strcpy(numbers, "1,2,3,4,5");
    const double sum = calculator_add(numbers);
    assert(equals(15, sum));
}

static void test_inputWithNewLines_insteadOfCommas_shouldStillBeParsed()
{
    strcpy(numbers, "1\n2,3");
    const double sum = calculator_add(numbers);
    assert(equals(6, sum));
}

static void test_inputWithMultipleCommasBetweenNumbers_shouldReturnTheSum()
{
    strcpy(numbers, "1\n,2,,,,,,,3");
    const double sum = calculator_add(numbers);
    assert(equals(6, sum));
}

static void test_inputWithCustomDelimiter_shouldChangeDelimiter()
{
    strcpy(numbers, "//;\n1;2");
    const double sum = calculator_add(numbers);
    assert(equals(3, sum));
}

int main()
{
    test_addEmptyString_shouldReturnZero();
    test_addOneNumber_shouldReturnThisNumber();
    test_addTwoNumbers_shouldReturnTheSum();
    test_addAnyQtyOfNumbers_shouldReturnTheSum();
    test_inputWithNewLines_insteadOfCommas_shouldStillBeParsed();
    test_inputWithMultipleCommasBetweenNumbers_shouldReturnTheSum();
    test_inputWithCustomDelimiter_shouldChangeDelimiter();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you show what your main looks like with some example input/parameters that cause the issue?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Added the whole main

Comment: `strtok(numbers, &linefeed)` is wrong. The `delim` parameter is a *pointer to a nul-terminated string* NOT *pointer to char* (see `man 3 strtok`) (**note:** the use of *string* in the *man page* description of `delim`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strtok` and `strcat` take a pointer to `char` array (i.e. string) and *not* a pointer to a `char` variable. That is, they need the string terminator (`'\0'`).

Also, in `calculator_add`, you didn't define enough space in `delimiters`, so your `strcat` would run past the end, causing undefined behavior.

I've annotated your source with the bugs and provided fixes. Where possible, I've done: `// NOTE/BUG: ... #if 0 /* original code */ #else /* fixed code */ #endif`:

```
static char DEFAULT_DELIMITER = ',';
char *calculator_retrieveFirstToken(char *numbers, const char * delimiters) {
    //if (delimiters[strlen(delimiters)-1] == DEFAULT_DELIMITER)
    if (delimiters[1] == DEFAULT_DELIMITER) {
        return strtok(numbers, delimiters);
    }
    else {
        // NOTE/BUG: this is incorrect -- you must pass a string pointer _not_
        // the address of a [single] character
#if 0
        char linefeed = '\n';
        strtok(numbers, &linefeed);
#else
        char *linefeed = "\n";
        strtok(numbers, linefeed);
#endif

        return strtok(NULL, delimiters);
    }
}

char calculator_findDelimiter(const char *numbers) {
    char delimiter = DEFAULT_DELIMITER;
    if (strlen(numbers) >= 4
        && numbers[0] == '/'
        && numbers[1] == '/') {
        delimiter = numbers[2];
    }
    return delimiter;
}

double calculator_add(char *numbers) {
    // NOTE/BUG: this defines only enough space for a single character and the
    // '\0' so when it is concatenated to, it is undefined behavior [you're
    // running past the end of the string]
#if 0
    char delimiters[] = "\n";
#else
    char delimiters[4] = "\n";
#endif
    char *token = NULL;

    // NOTE/BUG: this repeats the same mistake with the strtok above
#if 0
    char mainDelimiter = calculator_findDelimiter(numbers);
    strcat(delimiters, &mainDelimiter);
#endif

    // NOTE: either of these will fix the strcat
#if 0
    char mainDelimiter = calculator_findDelimiter(numbers);
    char temp[2];
    temp[0] = mainDelimiter;
    temp[1] = 0;
    strcat(delimiters, temp);
#else
    delimiters[1] = calculator_findDelimiter(numbers);
    delimiters[2] = 0;
#endif

    token = calculator_retrieveFirstToken(numbers, delimiters);
    return calculator_addEveryToken(token, delimiters);
}
```